# Turn off HTML Encoding in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-encode

I have a function that returns a snippet of JavaScript and/or HTML.

```
static public string SpeakEvil()
{
    return "<script>alert('BLAH!!');</script>";
}
```

In the view, Razor is quite rightly HTML encoding it, as most would expect.

```
@StaticFunctions.SpeakEvil()
```

How do I have Razor **not** HTML Encode this, so that the HTML and JavaScript are emitted verbatim, and that any script actually runs?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could use the `Raw()` function but it's mostly meant for things that come from the database.

For a helper like you have I would suggest returning an `IHtmlString`:

```
static public IHtmlString SpeakEvil() {
    return new HtmlString("<script>alert('BLAH!!');</script>");
}
```

That way you don't have have to call `Raw()` at every callsite.

Comment: I'm using the RazorEngine in a non-web application. Neither of your proposed solutions are working for me, in fact, the Html.Raw method call is giving me the following exception: "Unable to compile template. The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context". If I have a MvcHtmlString, or an IHtmlString it still html encodes the text but doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: I'm using the RazorEngine outside of a web application, and can't get this to work :( Any ideas?

Comment: @blesh & leypascua
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273327/how-to-prevent-escaping-html-in-razor-standalone
If you are using RazorEngine, then that is covered in this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273327/how-to-prevent-escaping-html-in-razor-standalone

Answer (score 39):

Use the [`Html.Raw`](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/) helper.

```
@Html.Raw(StaticFunctions.SpeakEvil())
```

Answer (score 4):

Return a `MvcHtmlString` (Inherits from `HtmlString`) by calling the `MvcHtmlString.Create()` method like so:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SpeakEvil()
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script>alert('BLAH!!');</script>");
}
```

You could also make it into an String extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HtmlSafe(this string content)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(content);
}
```

Source:
http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/04/10/lt-gt-htmlencode-ihtmlstring-and-mvchtmlstring.aspx

Comment: Nitpick, but when I see a method starting with "Is", I assume the method answers a question.  i.e. `IsDecimal(0m) => true`

Comment: Fixed :) IsHtmlSafe -> HtmlSafe