# How to prevent escaping html in Razor (standalone)?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Model with property Content which contains HTML string.

```
var model = new { Content = ... }
Razor.Parse(templateBody, model)
```

How can I render this string using standalone Razor.

I tried:

```
@(new HtmlString(Model.Content))
```

and also

```
@(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content))
```

Model.Content renders always HTML-escaped.

Comment: Have you seen this SO answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4973743/195550

Comment: The `@(new HtmlString(Model.Content))` should do the trick... try it with: `@((IHtmlString)new HtmlString(Model.Content))`

Comment: `Html.Raw(Model.Content)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display raw Html from database in ASP.NET MVC 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798334/is-it-possible-to-display-raw-html-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: I don't have HtmlHelper and other web helpers outside web project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In RazorEngine library special "do-not-escape-me" type is `RazorEngine.Text.IEncodedString`. Use simple helper method on template base class:

```
 @Raw("<script>alert('!');</script>")
```

To convince VS and Resharper to give you IntelliSense add following line at the top of template:

```
@inherits RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase
```

Comment: That's really quite annoying that it doesn't use IHtmlString like one would expect.

Answer (score 67):

this should work `Html.Raw(Model.Content)`

Comment: Simple and perfect!

Comment: this can lead to security problems like stored XSS and more