# Does ASP.NET MVC razor view engine encode HTML by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Does ASP.NET MVC razor view engine encode HTML by default?

Or do we have to use the `htmlhelpers` for html encoding the data.

Comment: It is apparently on by default, as there are questions [asking how to turn it off](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4973504/102937).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it does. Use `@Html.Raw(...)` to break that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Or use **HttpUtility.HtmlDecode**

```
string value1 = "&lt;html&gt;";                 // &lt;html&gt;
string value2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value1); // <html>
```